# Paypal sdk for windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, paypal, windows-phone-8.1

I am currently working with windows phone 8.1[RT] c# application. 
Is there any paypal sdk available for windows phone 8.1 . I have checked 
[windows8phonesdk](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PayPalWindows8PhoneSDK/) which is not available for windows phone 8.1.

If sdk is not available then how to integrate paypal in windows phone 8.1

Answer (score 2):

Well the paypal API has a rest interface: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/

So you can always just make calls using plain GET / POST request or as I suggest using RestSharp (http://restsharp.org/)

A simple example would be (without credentials):

```
var client = new RestClient("https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/orders/order-id");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply . I just want to know that rest api avalable for (Asia -pasafic)Indian market ?

Comment: @kushalmaniyar supported currencies: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-api-payment-country-currency-support/ but you can alsways call the code as from the US and convert stuff yourself.